# Pyqtgraph class: how to automatically update graph values from data buffer?

Tags: python, graph, pyqtgraph, graph-visualization

I am using the `pyqtgraph` module to make a nice and simple real-time graph. I want to make it as a class/object that can take in a data buffer, and on update, re-read the data buffer to draw the graph. I'm having some trouble getting data buffer values from outside the class code into the object.

Code below:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
# pip install pyqtgraph


class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, buffer_size, data_buffer, graph_title, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)

        #### Create Gui Elements ###########
        self.mainbox = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainbox)
        self.mainbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.canvas = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.mainbox.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.mainbox.layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.view = self.canvas.addViewBox()
        self.view.setAspectLocked(True)
        self.view.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0,0, 100, 100))

        self.numDstreams = 1
        self.bufferLength = buffer_size
        self.dataBuffer = data_buffer
        self.graphTitle = graph_title
        
        self.otherplot = [[self.canvas.addPlot(row=i,col=0, title=self.graphTitle)] # , repeat line for more
                           for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)]
        self.h2 = [[self.otherplot[i][0].plot(pen='r')] for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)] # , self.otherplot[i][1].plot(pen='g'), self.otherplot[i][2].plot(pen='b')
        self.ydata = [[np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength))] for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)] # ,np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength)),np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength))
        
        for i in range(0,self.numDstreams):
            self.otherplot[i][0].setYRange(min= -100, max= 100) 

        self.counter = 0
        self.fps = 0.
        self.lastupdate = time.time()

        #### Start  #####################
        self._update()

    def _update(self):
    
        
        for i in range(0,self.numDstreams):
            self.ydata[i][0] = np.array(self.dataBuffer)
            
            self.h2[i][0].setData(self.ydata[i][0])
            
        
        now = time.time()
        dt = (now-self.lastupdate)
        if dt <= 0:
            dt = 0.000000000001
        fps2 = 1.0 / dt
        self.lastupdate = now
        self.fps = self.fps * 0.9 + fps2 * 0.1
        tx = 'Mean Frame Rate:  {fps:.3f} FPS'.format(fps=self.fps )
        self.label.setText(tx)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, self._update)
        self.counter += 1
        
        
def CreateGraph(buffer_size, data_buffer, graph_title): 
        
    app1 = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp1 = App(buffer_size, data_buffer, graph_title)
    thisapp1.show()
    
    sys.exit(app1.exec_())
    return app1
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,)
    
    app = CreateGraph(100, test_buffer, "Activity Score")
    
    while 1:
        test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,)
        app._update()
```

The code works in that it draws an initial graph of the random data. However, it doesn't update in the loop as I'd want. When I use this object, I want it to update its graph data buffer based on an outside variable, as I'm trying. Instead it's stacking, i.e. it only reads the data for the first time.

### Edit

To be clear, I was expecting `test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,) app._update()` to update the graph continuously in the loop. I need the graph to be able to read a buffer variable in real-time and draw new data.

How can I do this?

Comment: you could explain yourself better, you expect `test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,)
        app._update() `update the graph?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping to have happen, I'll add to question.

Comment: How often do you want it to be updated?

Comment: The `Pyqt` graph module is really fast, essentially the update loop reads at hundreds of frames per second, and re-draws. So as fast as possible.

Comment: Okay, I understand you but do not expect more than 60FPS, your calculation of FPS is not correct, you are only counting the time the function is executed _update(), that does not guarantee that the painting is 300FPS as you are printing, Qt and all libraries graph does not automatically update the view if not when necessary, for example 60FPS is 16.6ms, assume that you place the data in 2ms intervals only then only 1 of every 8 data will be shown. I can make it update but I indicate that your calculation is not real.

Comment: That's fine, FPS isn't a big deal since in practice it's pretty fast anyways. Just need that real-time update from a buffer variable somehow.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, indicate that your calculations are incorrect so I will eliminate the `_update()` method from my answer.

Going to the point, the method `exec_()` creates an event loop that conceptually is a while True so that after that line no other line of code is executed, so your code from `while 1:` is never executed.

On the other hand if we eliminate it we could not place the `while 1:` inside the GUI thread since it blocks it and does not let the GUI review the various events or update the GUI for example the painting task.

Also if you use `test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,)` that does not imply that `self.dataBuffer` is updated, they are not linked.

The solution is to place the `while 1:` inside a new thread and send the data by signals to the main thread.

```
import sys

import threading

import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, buffer_size=0, data_buffer=[], graph_title="", parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)

        #### Create Gui Elements ###########
        self.mainbox = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainbox)
        self.mainbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.canvas = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.mainbox.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.mainbox.layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.view = self.canvas.addViewBox()
        self.view.setAspectLocked(True)
        self.view.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0,0, 100, 100))

        self.numDstreams = 1
        self.bufferLength = buffer_size
        self.graphTitle = graph_title

        self.otherplot = [[self.canvas.addPlot(row=i,col=0, title=self.graphTitle)] # , repeat line for more
                           for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)]
        self.h2 = [[self.otherplot[i][0].plot(pen='r')] for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)] # , self.otherplot[i][1].plot(pen='g'), self.otherplot[i][2].plot(pen='b')
        self.ydata = [[np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength))] for i in range(0,self.numDstreams)] # ,np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength)),np.zeros((1,self.bufferLength))

        for i in range(0,self.numDstreams):
            self.otherplot[i][0].setYRange(min= -100, max= 100) 
        self.update_plot(data_buffer)

    def update_plot(self, data):
        self.dataBuffer = data
        for i in range(0, self.numDstreams):
            self.ydata[i][0] = np.array(self.dataBuffer)
            self.h2[i][0].setData(self.ydata[i][0])


def CreateGraph(graph_title): 
    thisapp1 = App(graph_title=graph_title)
    thisapp1.show()
    return thisapp1

class Helper(QtCore.QObject):
    bufferChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

def generate_buffer(helper):
    while 1:
        test_buffer = np.random.randn(100,)
        helper.bufferChanged.emit(test_buffer)
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    graph = CreateGraph("Activity Score")
    helper = Helper()
    threading.Thread(target=generate_buffer, args=(helper, ), daemon=True).start()
    helper.bufferChanged.connect(graph.update_plot)

    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, I will test tomorrow. Regarding calculations (I think you're referring to FPS), I am not sure if they are correct, it is code I found elsewhere and just started to play with.

Comment: I tried it out, it's functional, but not exactly what I need. How can I include this class in another file, and then use a variable from other code as the data buffer (constantly being updated) that this object then reads and plots?

Comment: @JDS 
I do not understand, you will understand that your idea is very broad and abstract, my solution solves what you show, not what you want and do not place in your question. If you are not clear on your question do not expect an answer for what you do not mention.